# Adding Multiple Checbox Group to Django Admin Panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I want to add multiple checkbox to filter flowers at view according to checkbox selection. I'm very noob at Django. How can I modify my models.py ?

```
from django.db import models

class Flower(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    details = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def my_upload_to(instance, filename):
        return 'static/media/' + instance.name + '.jpg'
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=my_upload_to)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get done using forms, here is the code:

```
from django.forms import widgets
class FlowerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label='Name',queryset=Flower.objects.all(),
           widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    class Meta:
        model = Flower
```

Comment: There is not any change in admin panel. I understood that this codes add flower checkbox. I want to add checkbox of some properties od flowers and want to filter according to this properties at view.

Comment: you need to create custom form with selected checklist.

Answer (score 0):

some thing like this:

in views.py:

```
# get the selected flower id as fid
FlowerForm = create_flower_form(fid)
```

in forms.py:

```
def create_flower_form(id):
class fform(forms.ModelForm):

    name = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Flower type ',
            queryset=FLower.objects.filter(id=fid))


    class Meta:

        model = Flower

return fform
```